# How to Increase Import Size Limit in phpMyAdmin using Xampp server?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Does anyone know if or how you can increase the import size limit in phpMyAdmin? Currently my server is limited to 2MB.

Please note that this is not the same as the upload_max_filesize in php.ini. That value is set to 2MB.

I need to import a table into one of my DBs and the phpMyAdmin restriction of 50MB or more MB Data on the import is preventing me from doing that.